# Use same swap on two ubuntus with home encryption

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, encryption, swap

I have 2 14.04 in dual boot, both with home encryption. I would like them to use the same swap partition. One has a working swap partition (/dev/mapper/cryptswap1), but the other doesn't pick up the available swap.

How can I change that ?

Comment: Does the second one have an entry in `/etc/crypttab`?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the cryptswap1 line from the /etc/crypttab file in the system where the swap works to the same file in the the system where the swap doesn't work (copy the file if it doesn't exist yet).

Then copy the swap line from the /etc/fstab file in the system where the swap works to the same file in the the system where the swap doesn't work.